# Position element above keyboard on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a `div` which I would like to appear above the keyboard when it appears. I'm using JQuery to show and hide the toolbar when an input is focused on my page.

The `div` has the following CSS properties:

```
div.above-keyboard {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  ...
}
```

On an Android device, when the keyboard appears the `div` sits above the keyboard however on an iOS device the div sits behind the keyboard, as if the keyboard is not taking up the window space.

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks.